# How to create hive ddl using python

Tags: python, json, hadoop, hive

I recently started learning hive. I have a python list which has the following values

```
list=['hello:struct', 'env:string', 'element:struct','AppId:string','processId:string']
```

So using above values I need to create a hive DDL. Similar to this.

```
create table demo

{

hello :struct

<

   env:string,

    element:struct

      <

       AppId:string,

       processId:string

      >

>

formatted b\y..

location..
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the JSON serde. See here https://community.hortonworks.com/repos/30883/hive-json-serde.html

DDL you are after would be

```
CREATE TABLE demo
(
    hello struct 
    <
       env:string,
        element:struct
             <
               AppId:string,
               processId:string
             >
    >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/hive/demo';
```